# Why doesn't this simple program work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode

I'm trying to sort out everything concerning the way Unicode works in Windows console applications. Why doesn't this simple program work?

```
#include <iostream>

int wmain(int argc, const wchar_t* const argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
        std::wcout << argv[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with

```
>cl /EHsc /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Zc:wchar_t test.cpp
```

the program produces

```
> test.exe 1 2 3 abc абв
1
2
3
abc
```

Where is the fifth argument? I have to mention that `абв` fits into both my `GetACP()` and `GetConsoleCP()` & `GetConsoleOutputCP()` code pages (1251, 866 & 866). It's interesting that the program works (in a way) with the characters outside of those code pages:

```
> test.exe Sæter
Sцter
```

But:

```
> test.exe абв Sæter
```

Comment: If you do `test.exe 1 2 3 abc абв > output.txt`, is the output file correct?

Comment: @Benoit It's not, there's still no last line.

Comment: Try this: `printf("%d\n", argc);`.  What do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because `wcout` converts to narrow characters.

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193429/why-are-certain-unicode-characters-causing-stdwcout-to-fail-in-a-console-app) about this topic.

[Another good link](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/unicode-part-2-utf-8-stream-mode/).

Comment: So what's so special about converting to narrow characters? `абв` belongs to the code pages I use.

Comment: Ok, `std::wcout` does indeed set the `badbit`. Wonder why this happens, a proper investigation is to take place.