# `std::wcout << L"\u25a0" << std::endl;` outputs nothing, and anything <<'d to wcout thereafter also outputs nothing

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, unicode, console-application

On Windows, compiling and running this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main( ) {
    std::wcout << L"\u25a0" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Hello world!" << std::endl << L"Hello world!" << std::endl;
    }
```

produces no output. Why? (I've tried on different computers, and with different fonts)
[image]

Edit: \u25a0 is the code for ■; uploaded screenshot.

Comment: The default `codecvt` facet used by `wcout` takes a Unicode character and attempts to convert it to system default codepage aka `CP_ACP`. Apparently, `U+25A0` is not representable in the system codepage configured on your machine. So the conversion fails, `failbit` is set, at which point all further operations on this stream fail immediately (until `failbit` is cleared). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193429

Comment: Ahh ok. (Is this the best possible design?)