# Unicode range exceeds when try to print in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, character

I am trying to print Unicode characters in C++. My Unicode characters are Old Turkic, I have the font. When I use a letter's code it gives me another characters. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "\u10C00" // My character's unicode code.
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This snipped gives an output of another letter with a `0` just after its end.
For example, it gives me this (lets assume that I want to print 'Ö' letter):
`A0`

But when I copied and pasted my actual letter to my source snippet, from character-map application in ubuntu, it gives me what I want. What is the problem here? I mean, I want use the character code way `"\u10C00"`, but it doesn't work properly. I think this string is too long, so it uses the first 6 characters and pops out the `0` at the end. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After escape `/u` must be exactly 4 hexadecimal characters. If you need more, you should use `/U`. The second variant takes 8 characters.

**Example:**

```
"\u00D6"      // 'Ö' letter
"\u10C00"     // incorrect escape code!
"\U00010C00"  // your character
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` does not really support unicode, use `std::wstring` instead.
but even `std::wstring` could have problems since it does not support all sizes.

an alternative would be to use some external string class such as `Glib::ustring` if you use gtkmm or `QString` in case of Qt.

Almost each GUI toolkit and other libraries provide it's own string class to handle unicode.

Comment: Does `std::wstring` supports Private Use Are? Because if I could succeed my trials, I will use that area, since I have a project which involves multiple ancient language.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, see this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193429/why-are-certain-unicode-characters-causing-stdwcout-to-fail-in-a-console-app