# Using wstring and wcout doesn't get the expected output

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t, wstring, wchar

I'm writing a program in C++ which have to **handle unicode characters**.
The main problem is I use algorithms where I need to parse my s/wstrings **char by char** :

```
std::wstring word = L"Héllo"
for (auto &e : word)
// doing something with e
```

But if I run this :

```
std::wstring word = L"Héllo"
for (auto &e : word)
    std::wcout << e << std::endl;
```

I get this output :

```
H
?
l
l
o
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Do note that `word` prints properly when I use `std::wcout << word;`.

EDIT FOR  @Ben Voigt

Here is the out with `std::wcout << std::hex << std::setw(4) << (int)e << L" " << e << L'\n';`
 
:

```
  48 H
  e9 �
  6c l
  6c l
  6f o
```

Comment: Does your console support unicode?

Comment: Observation: Not dealing with a surrogate pair, because there's only one row of output for the unknown character.

Comment: It does because when I print all string in std::wcout I can see the 'é'

Comment: Would you mind adding the hexadecimal printout of the element values, e.g. `std::wcout << hex << setw(4) << (int)e << L"   " << e << L'\n'`;

Comment: `wchar`, `std::wstring`, and `std::wcout` are not unicode. AFAIK, they're just "wide characters" supporting 16-bit characters instead of 8-bit characters. Proper unicode would store everything as codepoints (which would have to be at least 32-bit) or use some kind of encoding scheme like UTF-8 (which is very common) or UTF-16/UCS-16 (which are commonly used in `std::wstring` but not mandated by the container)

Comment: @Xirema: The output shows that there are only 5 elements, no variable-length encodings, at least in this particular case.

Comment: Okay but should wide chars be able to store 'é' character ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm more just contesting the decision to tag this question with the `unicode` tag.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, I'm on Linux

Comment: @Ðаn Not sure about those dupes.  The OP says the full string prints properly, just not when it goes character by character.

Comment: @Xirema: Furthermore on Linux, `wchar_t` probably is 32-bit, capable of holding any Unicode codepoint without variable-length encoding.

Comment: @BenVoigt I edited the question with your line and its output.

Comment: There is the basic issue of putting quoted, non-ASCII string-literals in the source code itself.  It isn't guaranteed that what you typed inside those quotes are going to be the actual characters displayed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I already tried to read from strand input, result is same

Comment: I deleted my answer, so I copy here: `0xE9` is indeed the representation of `é` in wide unicode, so the output (the binary value, not the shown symbol) appears correct. I don't know why string output would differ or why the correct value doesn't work in your console.

Comment: The reason for the failure has to be that a different `operator<<` is selected when printing a single character, compared to an entire string.  To find out what is going wrong, one would need to write a custom `strreambuf` class that logs every call to `xsputn` and `overflow` and see how the call sequence varies.  To work around it, it might be enough to call `write` or `put` directly on `wcout`, or cast before using `<<`.  e.g. I expect that `wcout << wstring(1, e);` would get the "writing a whole string" behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To print the characters as you intend, try the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::wstring word = L"Héllo";
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    for (auto &e : word)
        std::wcout << e << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

More detailed description in this post: [Why are certain Unicode characters causing std::wcout to fail in a console app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193429/why-are-certain-unicode-characters-causing-stdwcout-to-fail-in-a-console-app)

Comment: These functions don't exist [on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44372286/using-wstring-and-wcout-doesnt-get-the-expected-output#comment75745817_44372286) do they?